# How to create dynamic menu in ASP.NET Core Razor Page with Web Api

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, menu

I get an error in when i add a MenuList into the Menus.cs, because in my MySql table have not MenuList there. But i cannot add a MenuList in Menus.cs, that means i cant create a dynamic menu properly, anyone have solution on this case? Please help me, i been stuck here about a week.

MySql Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Menusss(
    MenuId int not null auto_increment,
    MenuName varchar(250),
    ParentId int,
    ActiveNo int
);
```

Menus.cs:

```
public class Menus
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ActiveNo { get; set; }
    public List<Menus> MenuList { get; set; } = new List<Menus>();
}
```

MenusController.cs:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Menus>> GetMenus()
{
    List<Menus> menuList = new List<Menus>();

    foreach (Menus m in _context.menus.ToList())
    {
        menuList.Add(m);
    }

    List<Menus> menuTree = GetMenuTree(menuList, null);
    return menuTree;
}

private List<Menus> GetMenuTree(List<Menus> list, int? parentId)
{
    return list.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).Select(x => new Menus()
    {
        MenuId = x.MenuId,
        MenuName = x.MenuName,
        ParentId = x.ParentId,
        ActiveNo = x.ActiveNo,
        MenuList = GetMenuTree(list, x.MenuId)
    }).ToList();
}
```

MY.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {  
        buildMenu($('#menu'), data);
        $('#menu').menu();
    }
});

    function buildMenu(parent, items) {
        $.each(items, function () {
            var li = $("<li>" + this.MenuName + "</li>");
            if (this.ActiveNo == 0) {
                li.addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            }

            li.appendTo(parent);

            if (this.MenuList && this.MenuList.length > 0) {
                var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                ul.appentTo(li);
                buildMenu(ul, this.MenuList);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what compile error you get ,  can you mention ? OR do you get javascript error ?

Comment: Hi, i get this error "Unknown column 'm.MenusMenuId' in 'field list''"

Comment: Where did you get this error? I did not see any code refer `m.MenusMenuId`, is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I get this error in MenusController.cs at _context.menus.ToList()

Comment: When i add a List<Menus> MenuList in the Menus.cs, i will get an error when run

Comment: But i need to use the MenuList to store the menu children, any solution for me please